# fadeIn for html hover effect in a seperate div

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein

I have a html function in JQUERY that is causing text to appear to the right on a link hover.  I am curious if this text can fadeIn or something similar so it is not such a harsh transition.  Any help would be appreciated.

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#changeText").hover(function() {
$("#navhover").html("HOME");
}
,function(){
$("#navhover").html("")
});
});
</script>
```

HTML: (summarized I can show the full string if needed)

```
         <div class="nav"><a href="index.html" id="changeText">HOME</a></div>
         <p id="navhover"></p>
```

SITE:

www.monkbuns.com

Comment: Are you sure you want to empty the div after fading out?

Answer (score 0):

To fade in the text.

$("#navHover").hide().html("Home").fadeIn();

And to fade out

$("#navHover").fadeOut(function(){ $(this).html(""); });

Answer (score 0):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/cXJbH/)

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#navhover").hide();
    $("#changeText").hover(function () {
        $("#navhover").html("HOME").fadeIn("slow");
    }, function () {
        $("#navhover").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

Hope this helps, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#changeText").hover(function() {        
        $( "#navhover" ).hide().html("HOME").fadeIn( "slow", function() {
           // Animation complete
        });
    }
    ,function(){
       $("#navhover").html("")
    });
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GxJGs/